# Task update on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to design an application which creates a new employee data for an organization. My requirement is when a new employee record is being created by any existing user there is a main form of the application on which I need to show that an existing user has created a new user. For example, if the existing user is A and new user is B then the message on the main form should be as mentioned below:

A has created a new User B.

I am stuck in the place where I am not able to understand how to display this message on my main form.

For this do I need to keep listening to the database and in case any new row is created, then display the message accordingly or there is some other way as well as I do not want the application to keep hitting the database unnecessarily.

I am new to C# and so stuck here and need help.

Regards
Vineet More

Answer (score 0):

If you want only pass data from one form to another, you can either:

1) Use dependency injection to pass MainForm to CreateForm and then populate MainForm from that CreateForm (not that good idea).

2) Show CreateForm as Dialog form and return DialogResult when closing CreateForm.

Comment: Hi @Artur, Thanks for the reply. But how the Dialog Form will work in case multiple user Architecture and the application will be working on the client Server Model so at a time there can be multiple user creating viewing or modifying the user details. Any change has to be handled. Please let me know if this can be handled